# Remove 'Visual' tab from TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce

I would like to disable the 'Visual' tab so that the 'Text' tab is always used.

Is there a clean way to do this besides just doing something like .wp-switch-editor { display:none!important; }

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of three way you can do this

1. Log in to the Admin Control Panel and go to:

   Users -> All Users

   Find your username and click on Edit.

   Check "Disable the visual editor when writing"
2. Add this code in the themes function.php file

   ```
   add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );
   ```
3. Install a plugin like [Disable Visual Editor WYSIWYG](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-visual-editor-wysiwyg/)

Comment: Was looking for a development approach, not a user approach.  Adjusting the setting via the control panel would be a user approach, and having to resort to a plugin is never a good solution.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you try adding add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );

Comment: No, I just went with the other solution.

Comment: The filter approach is the way to go. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this style/script to remove the visual tab. It works for me.

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'custom_edit_page_js', 99);

function custom_edit_page_js(){ 
echo '  <style type="text/css">
        a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover, #qt_content_fullscreen{
            display:none;
        }
        </style>';
echo '  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#content-tmce").attr("onclick", null);
        });
        </script>'; 
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad solution. The Editor that shows initially will depend on what the user was last using. So if the user was using a visual editor on a different part of the site then comes to this page they will see the visual editor but just not the tab to select it. It would still require them to click the text tab to see the plain text version by which time the visual editor will have messed up the code.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to turn off WordPress TinyMCE rich editor (which will disable the Visual tab).

Add this piece of code to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter('user_can_richedit', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it the same way just adding the GET  page ID to target only certain pages:

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'removes_editor_visual_tab', 99 );

function removes_editor_visual_tab()
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    if($post_id == 1434){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover {
            display:none;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                document.getElementById("content-tmce").onclick = 'none';
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```